# DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

How do I populate the data from my database to the dataTable?

I tried to echo json_encode the data but when I try to call it on ajax I'm having the error

> "DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Invalid JSON response. For
> more information about this error, please see
> [http://datatables.net/tn/1"](http://datatables.net/tn/1%22)

Here is the result of echoing the json_encode

[image]

Here is the PHP code in `index.php`

```
$pdo = connect_to_database();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT date_time, water_level FROM water_level_logs');
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($data);
```

and here is my ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    'ajax': 'index.php',
    'columns': [
      { 'data': 'date_time' },
      { 'data': 'water_level' }
    ],
    "lengthMenu": [ 5, 10, 15 ]
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you follow the link and checked what was the response you got in the client?

Comment: @Cid Yes, the screenshot that was uploaded was the response from the XHR.

Comment: I would guess there is something additional in the response which _isn't_ JSON, either before or after what you've shown in the screenshot. I notice you say the code which echoes the JSON is in `index.php`. A script with that name is almost certainly going to also output some HTML for your page, I think? It would be easier for maintenance and debugging if you put the code which generates the JSON into its own file, which doesn't have any other jobs as well.

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#Types: _"Note that DataTables expects the table data to be an array of items in the `data` parameter of the object (use the ajax.dataSrc option of ajax as an object, if your data is formatted differently"_ - your JSON doesn't appear to be an object with a `data` property, but a plain array. So you will need to set the `dataSrc` option to an empty string.